# optimisation in Matlab: how to define constraints for parameters

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to estimate a Beta-Binomial model in Matlab (the data set is available [here](http://www.brucehardie.com/talks/prob3.xls)).

My likelihood function:

```
function  out= log_Lik(x,Data);

ms=Data(:,1);
xs=Data (:,2);

alpha=x(1)
beta=x(2)


P12=exp(gammaln(ms+1)-gammaln(xs+1)-gammaln(ms- xs+1)).*exp(gammaln(alpha+xs)+gammaln(beta+ms-xs)-gammaln(alpha+beta+ms));
P3= exp(gammaln(alpha+beta)-gammaln(alpha)-gammaln(beta));
P=P12.*P3;
Like=log(P);
out= -sum(Like);
```

My maximum likelihood estimation code:

```
Data=readtable('prob3.xls');

ms=Data.m_s;
xs=Data.x_s;

%% Data parsed to optimisation function
Data = [ms xs ];

f = @(x)log_Lik(x, Data);

%%
options = optimoptions('fminunc','Display','iter','Algorithm','quasi-  newton','MaxIter',10000,'TolX',10^-30,'TolFun',10^-30);
alpha0 = 1;
beta0=1;
x0 = [alpha0 beta0];
[x,fval,exitflag,output,grad,hessian] = fminunc(f,x0,options)
```

However, when I run the above code, I get an error saying:

```
Error using gammaln
Input must be nonnegative.
```

which I believe is coming from passing random negative values to `alpha` while optimising the likelihood function. Now I was wondering if there is any way to define a constraint for the values passed as my parameters (`alpha` and `beta`), when running the optimization command. Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use fmincon and add a constraint to keep alpha positive

Comment: Thanks Matthew! could you let me know where in my code and how this can be accommodated? Sorry I'm very new to matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fminunc`, the function you are currently using, finds a local minimum of an *unconstrained* optimization problem.

On the other hand, [fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) finds a local minimum of a constrained optimization problem.

It appears you have a constraint that alpha should be positive, so you should use fmincon and pass in the constraint.

fmincon operates similarly to fminunc. You should change "optimoptions('fminunc'..." to read "optimoptions('fmincon'..."

You want to set a lower bound of `[0; -inf]` to keep alpha non-negative. For the other inputs you don't care about, simply pass an empty array `[]`.

The [documentation for fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) is going to be clearer than anything I have the time to write here.